# How to print values inserted using a custom dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have made a custom jQuery-Ui dialog box.I want the dialog box to be called 12 times i.e. it should take input of 12 values and each value should be printed in a different box.The boxes should be created using a div tag.

So in the end on clicking a button the dialog box should pop up 12 times to take input and these 12 values should be printed on the webpage inside 12 different boxes which have to be created using div tag..

I have been able to make the custom dialog box take 12 inputs but not being able 2 display its contents in 12 different div boxes..

Please help...

Here is my code..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality
            </title <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes /smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />-->
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        width: 250,
                        height: 180,
                        modal: true,
                        show: "slow"
                    });
                    $('#put').click(function() {
                        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                    });

                });


                function getPdata(arg) {
                    var f = document.getElementById('pForm');

                    close();
                    return;
                }
                var cnt = 1;

                function getPdata1() {
                    var f = document.getElementById('pForm');
                    var n = f.name.value;
                    var n1 = f.name.value.toString();
                    //var a = parseInt( f.age.value );                          
                    alert(n1.length);
                    if (n1.length > 0 && n1.length <= 10) {

                        //alert( 'name: ' + n + '\n age: ' + a );
                        alert('name : ' + n);
                    } else {
                        alert('the data you have enterd is not in limit.Please try again');
                        return;

                    }
                    close();
                    if (cnt <= 12) {
                        f.name.value = "";
                        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
                        cnt++;
                    }

                }

                function close() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                }
            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <button type="button" id="put" onclick="click()">Insert data</button>
        </div>
        <div id="dialog" title="Input Data">
            <form id="pForm">name:
                <input type="text" name="name" width='50' maxlength="10" />
                <br>
                <br>
                <!--age: <input type="text" name="age" />
                <br>
                <br>-->
                <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="getPdata1()" />
                <input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="getPdata( this.value )" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mean 12 different dialog boxes have their own submit button, these action runs one by one. right?

Comment: button will be clicked only once..dialog boxes will appear 12 times one after the another after accepting data.After all 12 dialog boxes have accepted data only then will the 12 boxes be printed..

Answer (score 0):

using jquery,  `$('<div />'` to create new div element , `appendTo('body')` to add it to the body..i change your plain javascript to jquery too (like for getting value of input) jquery is readable, clear and much less code.. :) (and since you have already loaded the jquery library..why not use jquery..)

try this

```
 function getPdata1() {
      var n = $("input[name='name']").val();

      alert(n.length);
      if (n.length > 0 && n.length <= 10) {
           $('<div />',{id:"div" + cnt }).html(n).appendTo('body');  //crated div will have an id as `div`+ count;
      } else {
            alert('the data you have enterd is not in limit.Please try again');
             return;

      }
        close();
        if (cnt <= 12) {
             f.name.value = "";
              $("#dialog").dialog('open');
              cnt++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: when i am using this piece of code the dialog boxe is being displayed only once..how can i take input 12 times by calling the same dialog box again and again and then print the 12 different results all at once on the webpage???